# Isothermal versus Isometric/Isochoric

Tags: thermodynamics

My impression is that all three have something do with change in internal energy, in thermodynamics. But I cannot tell exactly  their relations.

First **isothermal**, which literally means zero temperature change. The relationship between change in internal energy (U) and change in temperature (T) is given by: $$\Delta U = \frac{3}{2} nR \Delta T$$

Then by my book says that the only two ways to transfer energy into and out of a closed system are by **work** and **heat**.

The way to transfer energy using **work** is through a piston exposed to the atmospheric pressure, as my book shows. And if the piston isn't moved, the **volume** stays constant. And so no **work** is done. So this is an **Isometric/Isochoric** process. But **is there any change in internal energy, for instance by a change only in temperature?** According to $\frac{PV}{nT} = R$, Temperature and volume are proportional. But pressure and and volume are too proportional. I am unsure  if a change In volume would necessarily lead to a change in temperature, and thus a change in internal energy.

Comment: You can make a big delta $\Delta$ via backslash Delta. Also, are you sure it "literally means zero temperature change"? 'zero' in Latin would be a word starting with 'n'.

Answer (score 1):

Given quasi static changes in an ideal gas, you can not change only the temperature and none of the other state variables.  If you keep pressure and volume constant and change temperature you will need to change the number of particles. But any change in temperature, given a fixed N, will indicate a change in internal energy of an ideal gas.

A change in volume doesn't alone imply a change in temperature.  But specifying the volume alone doesn't not fully represent your system so this is expected. Don't think of the equation of state as P,V~T. think of the equation of state specifying a surface in P,V,T space of the allowed pressure volume temperate configurations of your system and any quasi static change is constrained to this surface.

Answer (score 0):

To see if there will be any change of temperature for the problem of compressing an ideal gas one has to do the formal calculation. Look at the first law of thermodynamics:
$$ \Delta U = \Delta Q + \Delta W$$
or in the more formal way
$$d U = d Q -p d V$$
To be able to do an exact prediction one should know how the experiment is being conducted. For simplicity one considers an adiabatic process where no heat is exchanged between the closed system and the surroundings. The equation becomes $dU =-pdV$. Now plug in your equations from above $dU = \frac{3}{2}nR dT$ for the change in internal energy and $p=\frac{nRT}{V}$ for the pressure. It reads then
$$dU =\frac{3}{2}nR dT=-p dV =-\frac{nRT}{V}dV$$
or
$$\frac{3}{2T}dT = -\frac{1}{V}dV$$
Even before doing the Integration one can see here that the change in volume will result in change of the temperature and hence change in internal energy.